# vb.net web api $.ajax response not json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api2

Attempting a simple web api call in vb.NET that returns json so that the jQuery ajax response is already a javascript object.  Just can't seem to get it working.

```
' GET api/<controller>
Public Function GetValues()
    Dim json As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    json.Add("status", "success")
    json.Add("msg", "good job")

    Dim serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Return serializer.Serialize(json)

    'Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json)
End Function
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/products",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({key:'key'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);  // prints {"status":"success","msg":"good job"}
        console.log(response.status);  // prints undefined
    }
});
```

Chrome shows:
 
Request header: Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Response header: Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Network/Response tab shows:  "{\"status\":\"success\",\"msg\":\"good job\"}"

It's obviously not being turned into a javascript object automatically but I can't figure out why.  Doesn't matter if I return the response from JavaScriptSerialize.Serialize() or NewtonSofts JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

I must be missing something fundamental here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are getting json. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Based on all the docs I find for jQuery $.ajax() using dataType:'json' I should be getting a javascript object from the returned json string and so I should not have to do something like JSON.parse() to make it an object.  And so console.log(response.status) should print "success".  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the docs?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out my bonehead move. The function that was returning what I was serializing to json as a string until I told it otherwise. I had abandoned VB and switched to C# where it was failing too.  In the end I changed the C# versrion from:
`public string UploadFile()`
 to
 `public Dictionary<string, string> UploadFile()`
And it would be similar in VB something like
`Public Function GetValues() As String`
to
`Public Function GetValues() As Dictionary(Of String, String)`
Then I got a javascript object without having to use something like JSON.parse().  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. I have converted your JSON response to javascript object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/products",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({key:'key'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
    var objResponse = JSON.parse(response);

        console.log(response);  // prints {"status":"success","msg":"good job"}
        console.log(objResponse.status);  // prints undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: As I mention above, the docs indicate I don't have to use something like JSON.parse() and it's supposed to know that it's a json response and objectify it for me. No?

Comment: @JoelCool What you are getting in response is a string and you need to convert it to JSON/Javascript object in order to access its property. You can not access a property from string variable.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part.  I figured out my issue.  No matter what you use to serialize the server response (built in serialize routines or NewtonSoft) it will still come back as a string until you tell the function to return something else.  So I changed: <br /> Public Function GetValues()<br /> to:<br />Public Function GetValues() As New Dictionary(Of String, String)<br />and then it worked fine....  duh!

Comment: @JoelCool So you can mark it as a answer I guess :)